# Cannot open image

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to open an image using PIL image.open and its working fine on my local PC but when I try to do the same thing on Serve (Ubuntu) I get following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonscripts/0_resize.py", line 11, in <module>
    img = Image.open(dirName + imgName)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2309, in open
    % (filename if filename else fp))
IOError: cannot identify image file '/mnt/s3/testfolder/00123ca11af34b55acf093c67568400963163bd25ef034a1de0f02ec301cddf1.jpg'
```

Code I have used-

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
try:

   dirName = sys.argv[1]
   imgName = sys.argv[2]
   redType = sys.argv[3]


   img = Image.open(dirName + imgName)
```

Comment: the error message tells you that the file you're trying to open is not an image. Eventually when you transferred it, the format has been broken

Comment: Thanks @cur4so .. apparently its was the issue with s3fs that I used on server was cuasing this problem. I installed yas3fs and it worked like a charm.